# Group by id not grouping in php

Tags: php, mysql, count, group-by

im having a bit of a problem with my php script that counts the id column entries that match a certain questionnaire id. The results seem to be quite antisocial and just dont want to group up for some reason....

```
        $sql30 = <<<SQL
    SELECT id, COUNT(id) 
    FROM `QuestionnaireAnswers`
    WHERE questionnaireID='$questionnaireID'
    GROUP BY id
    SQL;
    if(!$result30 = $db->query($sql30)){ die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');}
    while($row30 = $result30->fetch_assoc()){
        if ($row30['COUNT(id)'] == '' OR $row30['COUNT(id)'] == '0'){$numberofresponses = '0';}
        else {$numberofresponses = $row30['COUNT(id)'];}    
    echo '<td>'.$numberofresponses.'</td>';
    }
```

If I use a sample questionnaireID of 1327809154 and run the following query in phpmyadmin :

```
SELECT id, COUNT( id ) 
FROM  `QuestionnaireAnswers` 
WHERE questionnaireID =  '1327809154'
GROUP BY id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I get the following results :

```
id  COUNT(id)
129 1
130 1
131 1
132 1
133 1
134 1
277 1
278 1
280 1
281 1
282 1
284 1
290 1
419 1
424 1
425 1
426 1
```

so.....it appears to be counting the results, but not grouping them to give me a total.........

EDIT,I have now changed it to :

```
        $sql30 = <<<SQL
    SELECT questionnaireID, COUNT(questionnaireID) 
    FROM `QuestionnaireAnswers`
    WHERE questionnaireID='$questionnaireID'
    GROUP BY questionnaireID
    SQL;
    if(!$result30 = $db->query($sql30)){ die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');}
    while($row30 = $result30->fetch_assoc()){
        if ($row30['COUNT(questionnaireID)'] == '' OR $row30['COUNT(questionnaireID)'] == '0'){$numberofresponses = '0';}
        else {$numberofresponses = $row30['COUNT(questionnaireID)'];}   
    echo '<td>'.$numberofresponses.'</td>';
    }
```

This returns :

```
questionnaireID COUNT(questionnaireID)
 1327809154 17
```

this works in phpmyadmin, but some reason nothing is returned in my script, the table column where the count should be is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDs are all unique, so they cannot be grouped. Only equal values are grouped together  and their count summed up.

Comment: ahh I see, so it would be better to group by questionnaireID ?

Comment: Ok that appears to work in phpmyadmin if I use questionnaireID, as it returns 17, but for some reason in my script output I still have a blank column in my table.

Comment: Yes, if you need it in the result. Otherwise you can just select `COUNT(id)`.

Comment: `$row30['COUNT(id)']` looks suspicious to me. Try to use `SELECT COUNT(id) AS count ...` and `$row30['count']` in your code.

Comment: Ok, iv sorted it now, the reason it didnt work after the edit was because I didnt define questionnaireID in the while loop. $questionnaireID = $row['questionnaireID'];

Answer (score 2):

You're query is simply getting all the ids and since each of them is unique, its displays the count as 1 for each of them, instead to get count of the number of responses just use

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `QuestionnaireAnswers` 
WHERE questionnaireID =  '1327809154'
```

Comment: since `count(id)` gives you the number of ids, which infact is the number of responses for that questionaire

Answer (score 0):

Ok, iv sorted it now, the reason it didnt work after the edit was because I didnt define questionnaireID in the while loop. $questionnaireID = $row['questionnaireID'];

Answer (score 0):

This returns the number of different non-NULL values​​.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `id`) 
FROM  `QuestionnaireAnswers` 
WHERE questionnaireID =  '1327809154'
```

You do not need `GROUP BY`, because you have only one `questionnaireID`.